# Itemrender of DataGroup won't release memory - flex(Adobe air)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, memory-leaks, air, desktop-application

i have a datagroup compoenent in Adobe Air application and i have used custom itemrenderer in it, i attached source code of itemRenderer as well as i attached profiling of it,

Question:
When i come back from other module to the module which have this datagroup at that time it again create Objects for itemrender and previous object of itemrender wont released.

if you have idea, please suggest me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="false"
                buttonMode="true"
                click="clickHandler(event)"
                mouseChildren="false"
                rollOut="rollOutHandler(event)"
                rollOver="rollOverHandler(event)"
                removedFromStage="itemrenderer1_removedFromStageHandler(event)"
                creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import coX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.event.ThumbEvent;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function image_completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                ConsoleUtils.logIt(" ThumbImage.mxml :image_completeHandler - ");
                image.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_completeHandler);
                fadeIn.target=image;
                fadeIn.play();
            }

            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                owner.dispatchEvent(new ThumbEvent("itemclick", data, itemIndex));
            }

            protected function rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                owner.dispatchEvent(new ThumbEvent("itemrollover", data, itemIndex));
            }

            protected function rollOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                owner.dispatchEvent(new ThumbEvent("itemrollout", data, itemIndex));
            }

            protected function itemrenderer1_removedFromStageHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                this.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, itemrenderer1_removedFromStageHandler);
                this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOutHandler);
                this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollOverHandler);
                this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

                this.removeAllElements();
            }

            protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                this.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler);
                image.source="test.png";
                //image.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, image_completeHandler);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Fade id="fadeIn"
                alphaFrom="0"
                alphaTo="1"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:BitmapImage id="image"

                   horizontalAlign="center"
                   smooth="true"
                   smoothingQuality="high"
                   verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:ItemRenderer>
```

Snapshot of Profiling[image: profiling_snapshot_which_shows_memory_leak]

as you can see, in profile, i have 21 orphan objects which won't recyle and profiling shows me that at saved at line no 12 while line no 12 is creation_complete event and i have removed it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used `DataGroup` as parent component and i have define above itemRenderer in `itemRenderer` property of the `DataGroup`, and in dispose function i have define `DataGroup.itemRenderer` is null in `DataGroup`. so it will eligible for GC. and i see that now no instance of itemRenderer is in memory.